# Restrict an img's height, and have it scale

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use CSS to limit an `img`'s height. If its height is greater than the one given, it should scale down to the desired height, and scale the width, as well. They have no parents.

I have come up with this:

```
img {
    max-height: 500px;
    width: auto;
}
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: what exactly happens when you say "it doesn't work"?  It should work just fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/sby8dpsa/

Comment: The code you are using should work. Most probably, you have other `CSS` rules applying, with a stronger selector. Please provide a [mcve] of your issue, so we could inspect and advise.

Comment: You don't even need the `width` declaration - `max-height` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make responsive than you should use % to the place of px ; this link will help you . https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using this image as a CSS background image while also using the 'background-size' property.

IE:

```
.img-wrap {
    background: url(/path/to/image.jgp) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; /* 'cover' is one of many other options */
}
```

[CSS background-size Property](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)